# Having issues parsing an event log (ID 4725) and outputting the target username field using Powershell

Tags: windows, rest, powershell, event-log, windows-server

Basically, I am trying to write some code that will run off of a scheduled task any time the event ID 4725 is triggered. This specific event states that a particular user had their AD account disabled (Windows Server 2016).

What I need to do is take the username from this event ID and output it as a variable #UserName to be used in the restmethod URI.

```
# Variables
$params = @{"action"="move";"destination"="/Shared/IT/Archived User Data/"}
$json = $params|ConvertTo-Json
$eventRecordId = 4725
$eventChannel = "Security"

# Gets the latest "disabled user account" event log and outputs the disabled user's name to a variable called $UserName


Get-EventLog –Log Security -InstanceId 4725 -Newest 1 | $UserName = ?{Group-Object -Property "TargetUserName"}

Echo $UserName 

# Calls the Egnyte API to move the disabled user's home folder to the archive folder
Invoke-RestMethod `
    -Method Post `
    -body $json `
    -Uri 'https://xxxxxx.egnyte.com/pubapi/v1/fs/private/"$UserName"' `
    -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
               Contenttype = "application/json"}
```

Expected results: Take the username from the target-username field in the security event-log ID 4725, output it to variable "#UserName", and then input it into the rest-method API.

Actual results: The variable is not being created.

Comment: `$UserName Get-EventLog` -- I don't see an `=` here.

Comment: PLEASE, fix your code formatting ... it is nearly unreadable. >>> How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML? - Help Center - Stack Overflow — https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: It would appear that in the reformatting of this post (thanks Lotpings for fixing it!) there was one thing left behind. It is fixed now.

Comment: So it works now? It shoudlnt work based on that pipe to $username

Comment: No, the original issue is still occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK Lets take a look at this Event 4725 template

```
(Get-WinEvent -ListProvider * -ErrorAction Ignore).Events |
        Where-Object {$_.Id -eq 4725} |
        select * | 
        Format-List
```

We can see there is a TargetUserName

```
<data name="TargetUserName" inType="win:UnicodeString" outType="xs:string"/>
```

So lets parse that Message into XML,
**Get-EventLog** returns a type **System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntry**

So first we need to change that object into a **System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord** so we can convert to **XML**

We can ether Make a new call using **Get-WinEvent** which will return the type **System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord** which has a method for turning data into XML

Or We can get the Index from the current record and call Get-WinEvent looking for the EventRecordID.

Below is a function i wrote that will parse the message field and make a new psobject with property ParsedMessage

```
function Parse-WindowsEvents(){
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=1, ValueFromPipeline)]
        #[System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventRecord[]]$Events
        [object[]]$Events
    )
    process{
        $ArrayList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
        $Events  | %{
            $EventObj = $_
            $EventObjFullName = $_.GetType().FullName
            if($EventObjFullName -like "System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntry"){   
                $EventObj = Get-WinEvent -LogName security -FilterXPath "*[System[EventRecordID=$($_.get_Index())]]"
            }elseif($EventObjFullName -like "System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord"){

            }else{
                throw "Not An Event System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord or System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntry"
            }
            $PsObject =  New-Object psobject
            $EventObj.psobject.properties | %{
                $PsObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $_.Name -Value $_.Value
            }
            $XML = [xml]$EventObj.toXml()
            $PsObject2 = New-Object psobject
            $XML.Event.EventData.Data | %{
                $PsObject2 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $_.Name -Value $_."#text"
            }
            $PsObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ParsedMessage -Value $PsObject2
            $ArrayList.add($PsObject) | out-null
        }
        return $ArrayList
    }
}

$Username = Get-EventLog –Log Security -InstanceId 4725 -Newest 1 | Parse-WindowsEvents | select -ExpandProperty ParsedMessage | select TargetUserName
$Username.TargetUserName
#or
$Username = (Get-EventLog –Log Security -InstanceId 4725 -Newest 1 | Parse-WindowsEvents | select -ExpandProperty ParsedMessage).TargetUserName
$Username
```